# Keycloak and JBoss: Edit location of config file keycloak.json

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, keycloak

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.2, JavaEE 6.0 and keycloak-eap6-adapter-dist 6.0.1 for authentication against Keycloak.

The keycloak.json is currently packed in the deployed war archive (under WEB-INF), so it is not interchangeable for each customer.

Do you know how to change the path of keycloak.json to a external path to make it interchangeable by each installation/stage (e.g. using Docker)?

---

Solution: Thanks to ravthiru we implemented a custom config resolver like this:

```
public class CustomKeycloakResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {

    private KeycloakDeployment deployment;

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
        if (deployment != null) {
            return deployment;
        }

        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(System.getenv("KEYCLOAK_CONFIG_FILE"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        deployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(is);
        return deployment;
    }
}
```

and registered it in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>keycloak.config.resolver</param-name>
    <param-value>my.package.CustomKeycloakResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now you can specify the path directly with an environment variable in your Docker-Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to resolve keycloak configuration dynamically using `keycloak.config.resolver` context-param in your `web.xml` 
You can find more about this configuration in keycloak [document](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_multi_tenancy) and sample implementation [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/multi-tenant)